# Создание СУБД без использования CMS

Tags: php, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. Собственно вопрос заключается в следующем - встречались ли вам какие то уроки или статьи по данной теме, где незамысловато и разжевано описана данная тема? Может есть какие то конкретные ресурсы посвященные этому вопросу? Единственное условие в том, что при написании данной субд нельзя использовать какие то CMS. Заранее благодарю за ваши ответы и комментарии по данной теме.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть [записи отличного курса по базам данных](http://www.lektorium.tv/course/22977), там студентам в процессе обучения (для сдачи экзамена) как-раз нужно было написать СУБД. Но сразу предупреждаю, это не инструкция вида «напишите это, а потом вот это». В курсе даётся теория, разбираются некоторые СУБД и приёмы, но предполагается что студент будет думать головой.

Кроме того я вообще не уверен что правильно понял что вы хотите получить в результате. Опишите задачу подробнее. Но если мои предположения верны то php не лучший выбор для такого приложения.

Comment: P.S. в любом случае рекомендую этот курс всем кто интересуется СУБД, он весьма толковый.

Comment: По сути эта информация мне нужна для написания курсовой работы по БД. Как мне объяснила преподавательница, нужно сделать "дружественный интерфейс для работы с БД, который будет понятен даже бабушкам". Т.е. реализовать такие моменты как create, update, delete, не командами, а через кнопки. Момент о выборе языка, да возможно не угадал с этим.

Comment: Так нужен пользовательский интерфейс к базе данных или СУБД? Это принципиально разные вещи, хотя если очень захотеть то можно доказать что это одно и тоже.

СУБД это вские там MySQL, Redis, Casandra, MongoDB простихоспаде на худой конец.

А пользовательский интерфейс это, по большому счёту, любая программа которая работает с СУБД и предоставляет пользователю (подразумевается конечный пользователь) какой-то интерфейс. Можно сказать что этот сайт — интерфейс к некоторой базе данных (в которой лежат вопросы, ответы, комментарии и прочее).

Comment: Писать СУБД на PHP это либо для истинных джедаев, либо для мазохистов (а скорее для джедаев-мазохистов). PHP рассчитан нат о что-бы на каждый запрос посетителя порождать новый процесс, независимый от всех прочих, не разделяющий с ними никаких данных (разделяемые данные хранятся во внешней БД). И эти процесс завершаются как только обработают запрос (кто-то вроде умудрялся писать демонов на php, но это изврат). В таком подходе есть свои плюсы и минусы, но для создания СУБД он подходит очень плохо. А вот для пользовательского интерфейса это вполне приемлемый подход.

Comment: Но я-бы всё-таки порекомендовал сразу привыкать к хорошему, т.е. к Python (это то самое место где фанаты других ЯП начинают кидаться в меня тяжёлыми предметами). И дабы не быть зверски избитым упомяну так-же про другие хорошие языки программирования используемые для написания веб-бекэндов: Ruby (подразумевается фреймворк Ruby on Rails), Java (если уметь её правильно готовить), Scala (те кто задолбался готовить Java — очень рекомендуют) и возможно Clojure (хотя язык этот сейчас маргинален, и я не уверен что это хороший выбор в качестве первого ЯПа)

Comment: @MrClon Спасибо за развернутый ответ)